# How to make Google Play like TextView animation when text is too long?

Tags: android, animation, textview

In Google Play when the name of a certain title is too long then they apply an animation on this `TextView` when the name is going out from one end of the `TextView`, goes in from the other end, stops for a second on the beginning of the Title text, and then goes for the next round.

Does anyone have any explanation how can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you talking about 'text marquee' Or multiline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was what worked for me, you have to actually request for focus in order for the marquee animation to work:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/cups_white"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">
        <requestFocus 
          android:focusable="true" 
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
          android:duplicateParentState="true" />
    </TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file where the TextView is declared you can use the following attributes:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:singleLine="true"
```

with the singleline you going sure thats the Text is showend only in one line.

For more details look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: It look like the right answer, but for some reason it does not do the trick for me, the text just ends with ".." without any animation.

Comment: ok, please try to add the following: android:scrollHorizontally="true" too

Comment: What did the trick for me was to call ``setSelected(true)`` programmatically on the TextView.